# How do you split a long value at every n digits, and then add it to a List in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, long-integer

I have converted a String value that consists solely of numbers into a Long value. Now I want to split this Long value every n digits, and add those "sub-Longs" into  a List.

```
Long myLong = Long.valueOf(str).longValue();
```

I want to split `myLong` at every nth digits, and add those sections into a `List<Long>`.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Your question is under-specified.  Splitting a number every `n` digits is insufficient as a requirement.  You need to specify whether the grouping happens from the left or right, i.e. what do you want if the number of digits is not an exact multiple of `n`.  Does the short sub-result come from the left or right in the original number?  Also, `Long.MAX_VALUE` has only 19 digits, is `Long` wide enough for your "long" numbers? Should you be using `BigInteger` instead?

Answer (score -1):

Would have to use `String.substring(...)` to make this work. That and a `for` loop. <strike>I'm going to edit in the rest of the code.</strike> Edited in. Explanatory comments added as well.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Just for testing.
    StringGrouper grouper = new StringGrouper();

    // Have tested for 2, 3, 4, and 5
    List<Long> output = grouper.makeList(12892374897L, 4);

    // Sends out the output. Note that this calls the List's toString method.
    System.out.println(output);
}

/**
 * @param l
 * @param spacing
 */
private List<Long> makeList(long l, int spacing) {

    List<Long> output = new ArrayList<>(Math.round(l / spacing));
    String longStr = String.valueOf(l);
    // System.err.println(longStr);

    for (int x = 0; x < longStr.length(); x++) {

        // When the remainder is 0, that's where the grouping starts and ends
        if (x % spacing == 0) {

            // If it does not overflow, send it in
            if ((x + spacing) < longStr.length()) {

                String element = longStr.substring(x, x + spacing);
                // System.err.println(element);
                output.add(Long.parseLong(element));

            } else {
                // If it does overflow, put in the remainder
                output.add(Long.parseLong(longStr.substring(x, longStr.length())));
            }
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```